# Redux: How to do something other than reducing or rendering when an action is sent

Tags: redux

I am trying to understand the concepts behind redux.

Consider this very simple UI:

```
 +-------+-------+-------+
 | Tab A | Tab B | Tab C |
 |       +--------------------+
 | one ................ $1.22 |          
 | two ................ $3.22 |
 | three ............ $211.99 |
```

The state has an object `itemsById` and an array `currentlyVisibleItemIds` and is easily rendered.

I also have a websocket open which delivers constant price updates and forwards them using `store.dispatch()`. The reducer creates a new updated `itemsById` object and prices re-render. All good.

However, for efficiency reasons I only want to listen to price updates of currently visible items so I have to send a subscription command through the socket whenever `currentlyVisibleItemIds` changes.

For the life of me I cannot find a good place to put this logic. If I do `store.subscribe()` in the websocket code I get *all* changes and have to manually figure out if `currentlyVisibleItemIds` changed. Calling into the websocket from the reducer feels very wrong. Should this go into a thunk so that the websocket code is called from within the action?

Any suggestions appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I currently have. Seems a bit clunky because I have to manually figure out if `currentlyVisibleItemIds` has changed:

```
function PriceFeed(port, store) {

    var webSocket, isConnected, previousItems, unsubscribeFunc;

    function onOpen() {
        isConnected = true;
    }

    function onMessage(event) {
        var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (json.type === 'updates') {
            store.dispatch({
                type: 'PRICE_UPDATES',
                data: json.prices
            });
        }
    }

    function storeChangeHandler() {
        if (!isConnected) {
            return;
        }
        var currentItems = store.getState().currentlyVisibleItemIds;
        if (currentItems != previousItems) {
            webSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                type: 'subscription',
                ids: currentItems
             }));
            previousItems = currentItems;
        }
    }

    webSocket = new WebSocket(`ws://${location.hostname}:${port}`);
    webSocket.addEventListener('message', onMessage);
    webSocket.addEventListener('open', onOpen);
    unsubscribeFunc = store.subscribe(storeChangeHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`redux-thunk` should handle this pretty well, assuming you are tracking your visible items in the store. In your message receieved WS callback, you can do this:

```
store.dispatch(PriceUpdate(itemID, price))
```

where `PriceUpdate` is defined as

```
function PriceUpdate(itemID, price) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (getState().visibleItems.includes(itemID)) {
      dispatch({ type: PRICE_UPDATE, payload: { itemID, price });
    }
  }
}
```

That said, I would be wary of prematurely optimizing here. In most cases, even up to a very large number of transactions, it is probably worth it to just keep all your local data fresh, regardless of whether its in view. But of course, I don't know the context here, and there are definitely situations where this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. Sorry for not being clear enough: I'm not so much struggling with getting data **out of the socket** into react/redux but getting a change event out of redux **into the socket**. As for optimization you are probably right. I am more worried about the socket being overloaded (100s of items, some updating multiple times per second) than rendering but should really measure load first.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to initiate changes? How are prices changing on the front-end if they aren't visible, for example?

Comment: I've added my current solution, hope that makes things clearer. Change is initiated by a message coming through the socket much like in your example